# WCF Json Service giving 404 error message

Tags: c#, json, wcf, web-services

**BACKGROUND**

I have a WCF XML web service and need to convert it to use JSON instead. It is hosted inside a Windows Service (if that matters at all).

**PROBLEM**

I keep getting a 404 status response.

**INTERFACE:**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/Search")]
SearchResponse Search(RequestInfo requestInfo);
```

**CONSOLE APP:**

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";

    var request = new RequestInfo
    {
        //etc
    };

    using (var upStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(RequestInfo));
        serializer.WriteObject(upStream, request);

        byte[] responseBytes = client.UploadData("http://localhost:8000/TheService.svc/Search", "POST", upStream.ToArray());

        using (var downStream = new MemoryStream(responseBytes))
        {
            var deserializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Response));
            var result = deserializer.ReadObject(downStream) as Response;
            return result.SearchResult.QueryId;
        }
    }
}
```

**OTHER**

I have also tried using Fiddler 2.0 and directly passing in the JSON request like so:

```
POST http://localhost:8000/TheService.svc/Search HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Fiddler
Content-Length: 209
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expect: 100-continue
Host: localhost:8000

{my json here}
```

However, that just confirms the 404. What am I missing here?

**UPDATE:**

Just to note, I can actually browse to `http://localhost:8000/TheService.svc` and that works fine. It displays the standard web service page created by WCF.

Comment: try changing the port

Comment: @Kyle, that won't help. It was working perfectly fine on that port when it was an XML web service. I have only changed it to JSON. If it was a firewall issue, it wouldn't have worked with the XML version either.

Comment: I think `TheService.svc` in url is wrong. See your config file.

Comment: @I4V Thanks, but it is correct. I should have mentioned: I can actually browse to `http://localhost:8000/TheService.svc` and that shows the standard web service page created by WCF services.

Comment: @Matt When I register your service as `http://0.0.0.0:8000/TheService.svc` and invoke it(in c#) with `http://localhost:8000/TheService.svc/Search` it works.. BTW: your error is clear `404: page not found`

Comment: @I4V What do you mean by 'register'? You mean set that in the web.config of the service and client?

Comment: I tested your code with standalone host `WebServiceHost w = new WebServiceHost(typeof(TheService), new Uri("http://0.0.0.0:8000/TheService.svc"));` I don't like to deal with WCF configs much :)

Comment: I need to have all settings in app.config, so I change it to `http://0.0.0.0:8000/TheService.svc` in there and it still runs the service page on localhost, but I also still get the 404 when posting to `/Search`

Comment: @Matt Add this method to your service **`[OperationContract][WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
            public string Hello()
            {
                return "test";
            }`** and try to get the json result from your browser. When you get it, you have also found the correct url for your other method. This url works for me `http://localhost:8000/TheService.svc/hello`

Comment: @I4V, I tried that but get a 405 error: `Method Not Allowed`

Comment: @I4V In Fiddler, I use GET and it gives the 405. Then when I try POST it gives a 404..

Comment: @Matt 404 means, your url is not correct. 405 means your url is correct but you do something wrong like requesting a GET while the method expects a POST etc...

Comment: @I4V I know what it means, thanks. However, I cannot understand why I am getting those errors. Everything looks fine to me. I am obviously missing something, but I can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, something in the web.config was causing the problem (`<system.serviceModel>` section). I just decided to remove everything in that section and start with a bare bones config and then build up from there... now it works.. I did not take the time to try with each and every option I had before, so I don't know exactly which option was causing the problem. If anyone gets this same problem, I advise starting with a basic config and building up from there.

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you show your web.config code as well.

use

```
   UriTemplate = "Search"
```

instead of `UriTemplate = "/Search"`

try 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost

instead of `http://localhost:8000/TheService.svc/hello`

remove it `BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped` or instead use

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare
```